# Modifying all values Excel/CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, cmd

I have an issue and I'm not sure how to handle it.

I have a Excel/CSV file and I need to modified it. I need to add quotation marks to all the cells.

This is what I have

```
Matter,TK,FeedT,Blank1,Blank2,Date,Time,Blank3,Blank4,Description
```

This is what I need

```
"Matter","TK","FeedT","Blank1","Blank2","Date","Time","Blank3","Blank4","Description"
```

Any suggestion on where to look?

Comment: I know you're asking a Python solution, but you could also just use **Notepad++** and install the `CSV Lint` plugin. In the Reformat dialog use Apply Quotes option to "All values".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.  This will also handle cells with newlines and embedded double quotes by escaping them properly.

```py
import csv

# Note: Python 3.10+ required for this with syntax; otherwise, use two withs
with (open('input.csv', newline='') as fin,
      open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout):

    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

input.csv:

```
Matter,TK,FeedT,Blank1,Blank2,Date,Time,Blank3,Blank4,Description
```

output.csv

```
"Matter","TK","FeedT","Blank1","Blank2","Date","Time","Blank3","Blank4","Description"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was mostly sure using the csv module was the solution, but I didn't know how to get quotes on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
cells = line.split(',')
line = ''
for cell in cells
    line = '"' + cell + '",'
if line[-1] == ','
    line = line[0:line.len() - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should take you from the reading of the file to the rewriting of it, if that is your aim.

```
newFile = ""
with open('some.csv', "r") as csv_file:
    for row in csv_file:
        entries = row.split(",")
        result = list(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"', entries))
        newFile += ",".join(result)
        newFile += "\n"
with open('some.csv', "w") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(newFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excel and python a lot, get familiar some Pandas tricks that help interfacing with excel. Here's a simple copy/paste approach.

1. Copy the header of the excel document:
2. Run the python code in a jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.columns = [f'"{col}"' for col in df.columns
df.to_clipboard(index=False)
```

3. Paste the updated columns into the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Excel file, you can use the `openpyxl` module like so:

```
import openpyxl as xl
filename = <*path-to-file*>
workbook = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = workbook.active
for i in range(ws.max_row):
    for j in range(ws.max_column):
        curr_value = ws.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value
        if curr_value == "None":
            continue
        new_value = f'"{curr_value}"'
        ws.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value = new_value

workbook.save(filename)
```